# WebView doesn't mantain login session

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a browsable webview but unfortunately when I open a new page inside the webview i loose the login state and have to login again.

here my code:

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webArea);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
}

CookieSyncManager.createInstance(Home.this);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();


    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading");
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
    wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            dialog.show();
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    });
    wv.loadUrl(url);

    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to set cookieSyncManager -

`CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mWebView.getContext());`

If doesn't work, then we will have to check how your URL navigates.